# Как найти общий шаблон для всех слов в предложении?

Tags: c, регулярные-выражения

столкнулся с задачей:

На вход программе подается текст. Для каждого предложения вывести строку образец удовлетворяющую каждому слову в предложении.

Строка условия содержит символы:

- `?` - один или больше любых символов, в начале и конце образца могут быть символы
- `*` - обозначающие 0 или больше символов.

Например, для слов `Аристотель` и `Артишок`, строка образец будет иметь вид `Ар???о?*`.

Была идея реализовать все через циклы, но получается настолько сложно, что все время путаюсь и готовой программы не получается. Посоветовали использовать регулярные выражения, но я от слова совсем не могу найти как их применить к этой задаче. Исходный код огромный и довольно непонятный. Как решить эту задачу? Язык С.

Comment: Формально `?*` должно ко всему подойти. Более правильно, наверное, искать максимально длинные общие для всех слов последовательности символов и вставлять '?*' между ними

Comment: Смотрите [наибольшую общую подпоследовательность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Получите наиболее длинный список общих букв. Между ними вставите вопросики. Группы вопросиков замените на звёздочки. Это решение применимо не только к паре слов, но к любому их количеству.